# Will netplan.io be used in Debian Buster?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, netplan

[Netplan.io](https://netplan.io) is a relatively new network interface configuration tool.  It came to my attention because it has become the ["default" way to configure interfaces on Ubuntu](https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2018/9/how-use-netplan-network-configuration-tool-linux).

What about Debian itself?  Are there plans to integrate netplan.io and replace `/etc/network/interfaces` like has been done in Ubuntu?  I can see that netplan.io is [included in Debian Buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/netplan.io).  Will it be installed by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s been no mention on netplan.io on [the Debian development mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel), and `ifupdown` still has “[Priority: important](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ifupdown/blob/master/debian/control)” for Debian 10, so I think the default will remain `ifupdown`.

Even if the default switched to systemd networking or Network Manager, there’s another obstacle to the use of netplan.io in the default installation, which is that it requires Python. (Its use by default in Ubuntu is less surprising since [netplan.io is developed by Canonical](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/11/msg00272.html).)